# error: Instance member 'cropImage' can't be accessed using static access

Tags: flutter, dart

```
class ImagesCropper {
static Future<File?> cropImage(XFile file) async {
final File? croppedImage = await ImageCropper.cropImage(
  sourcePath: file.path,
  aspectRatioPresets:
      Platform.isAndroid ? crossAspectRatioAndroid : crossAspectRatioIos,
  androidUiSettings: androidUiSettings,
  iosUiSettings: iosUiSettings,
);
return croppedImage;
}
}
```

i put the full code here:

https://controlc.com/9590e7b1

and here's the error in debug console
debug console

[image: debug console]

Comment: Can you post your ImageCropper class?

Comment: https://controlc.com/9590e7b1

Comment: From image_cropper 1.5.0's [CHANGELOG](https://pub.dev/packages/image_cropper/changelog#150---2022-02-19): "BREAKING CHANGE: change `cropImage()` to instance method"

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It looks like you are using the ImageCropper package. https://github.com/hnvn/flutter_image_cropper/blob/master/lib/src/cropper.dart#L61 There was an error because the method isn't static so you have to create a new instance of the class to access it

```dart
await ImageCropper().cropImage...
```

The full code correction is below

```dart
class ImagesCropper {
static Future<File?> cropImage(XFile file) async {
final File? croppedImage = await ImageCropper().cropImage(
  sourcePath: file.path,
  aspectRatioPresets:
      Platform.isAndroid ? crossAspectRatioAndroid : crossAspectRatioIos,
  androidUiSettings: androidUiSettings,
  iosUiSettings: iosUiSettings,
);
return croppedImage;
}
}
```

Answer (score 27):

Just change `ImageCropper.cropImage` to `ImageCropper().cropImage`. This will use a new  instance of ImageCropper.